# Google sheet automatic addition of the number of items

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, counter, counting

hello to all who are able to help me I apologize in advance because I know it's somewhere on stackoverflow but I can't find it

I need it to automatically assign me a number to the selected column
(do not look at the date in columns C and D)
in column B there are unique repeatable names and I want it to have a number assigned depending on which time it has already been written
and I would like it to be dependent on column E as well

I don't want something like that
[image]

just something like this
[image]

Thanks for Help

I looked on the website but I couldn't find it, I know it's there somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in A2:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(B2:B; B2:B; ROW(B2:B); "<="&ROW(B2:B)))
```

Comment: is it possible to add another criterion using column E ? ?

Comment: @VoDAyToN yes, you can add multiple criterions

Comment: =INDEKS(LICZ.WARUNKI(B2:B; B2:B; WIERSZ(B2:B); "<="&WIERSZ(B2:B);E2:E; E2:E; WIERSZ(E2:E); "<="&WIERSZ(E2:E) ))

Comment: hi, is it possible to index in this formula by a fragment of text? for exemple looking at the picture in column B I would like to count the word E3